# Get paragraph delta/weight in template

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I have defined a paragraph type that has a text field and an image field. At the moment the twig template is something like this

```
<div class='paragraph_wrapper'>
  <div class='text-container'>{{ content.field_text }}</div>
  <div class='image-container'>{{ content.field_image }}</div>
</div>
```

The problem is I want to alternate the positions of the text & image containers for each paragraph. For example the first one would have text then the image, the next would have the image then the text and so on.

How do I get the paragraph template to be aware of its order in the list? If I use a preprocess function how do I get the order than pass the value as a variable to Twig?

Comment: rather than adding the classes in the paragraphs template, create a template file for each field and add the classes there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what template you're using, and I'm not sure how your site is setup. But if you have a template that is looping through and displaying these paragraphs, you can add a check in your twig file that checks if the paragraph is even or odd.

```
{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
    {% if loop.index is divisibleby(2) %}
        <div class='text-container'>{{ paragraph.field_text }}</div>
        <div class='image-container'>{{ paragraph.field_image }}</div>
    {% else %}
        <div class='image-container'>{{ paragraph.field_image }}</div>
        <div class='text-container'>{{ paragraph.field_text }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would work assuming the neither of these fields are set to `unlimited` values.

Comment: if that's the case couldn't you just nest it like so {% for text in paragraph.field_text %} ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) for sorting content, and then it will be very easy to output without extra logic.